# Please check my code to add linkbutton and click event programmatcally in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linkbutton

i wrote following code to create a linkbutton programmatically, but its showing like lable at runtime not as link

```
Dim lnkbutton As LinkButton = New LinkButton()
lnkbutton.ID = "HostelsClub" & dr("dshotelid").ToString()
lnkbutton.Text = "HostelsClub"
lnkbutton.PostBackUrl = Request.Url.ToString()

lnkbutton.ToolTip = "Click here To Book"
AddHandler lnkbutton.Click, AddressOf lnkBook_Click
PHbook.Controls.Add(lnkbutton)
```

Comment: How does the `Request.Url` look like? What is the html source for the linkbutton, when you do a "view source"?

Comment: its not showing any postbackurl in it

Comment: looking like this:
<a id="ctl00_CPH1_HostelsClub14944" title="Click here To Book" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$CPH1$HostelsClub14944','')">HostelsClub</a>

Comment: Now its showing link but not able to file click event and call funtion : lnkBook_click

Comment: Does clicking on the link cause page to refresh (or make a post)? In what page event, are you adding the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is not with your link button you need to add event handler for link button in page's init function .. than only it will work..

Comment: wow..really. i remember i have read it once..i am sure it will work